# Coin value wont save every time I run my game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2d game on unity, and I have a script that saves my coin value, but it doesn't save when I open the after getting more coins.

This is my script that saves the data:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Coin : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            PlayerPrefsManager.coins += 1;
            PlayerPrefsManager.UpdateCoins();
        }
    }
}
```

And my script that displays the data:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CoinsDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Text text;
    void Start()
    {
        text = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        string[] temp = text.text.Split('X');
        text.text = temp[0] + "X: " + PlayerPrefsManager.coins;
    }
}
```

player prefs manager script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerPrefsManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public const string Coins = "Coins";
    public static int coins;
    void Start()
    {
        coins = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coins");
    }


    public static void UpdateCoins()
    {

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Coins", coins);
        coins = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coins");
        PlayerPrefs.Save();

    }

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use PlayerPrefs to store game state.

Comment: @Draco18snolongertrustsSE is correct.  With that said, do you see the number of coins updating while playing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work fine, but I guess you've forgotten to assign your PlayerPrefsManager script to a gameObject. Cause if its Start doesn't execute, we will get the same result.

By the way, use your const string 'Coins', you've just declared it but you're not using it in these calls: SetInt, GetInt.

And try to update PlayerPrefs (PlayerPrefs.Save()) less often, since it writes data on the disk and is a little expensive to do it each time your coin's value changes. You can have a method called 'save' on your prefManager to only get called when you're done with the level, mission is complete etc... , or if you don't want to lose the data, call it less often, like once in each 10 seconds (take a look at [Invokerepeating](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html))